# How to make a stratified random sample with panel data in Rstudio?

Tags: r, sampling, panel-data

I want to do a stratified random sample of panel data. How to do it?

Example:
the most similar situation is the dataset Guns, included in the AER package of "R". it has 51 states, 13 variables over 23 years. Here 2 situations:

1. how to make a stratified random sample of 40 states?
2. how to make just a random sample of size=40 states?

I tried with this:

```
set.seed(2)

samp1=strata(Guns, ("levels(Guns$state)"), size=c(40), method = "srswor")
```

but an error is returned:

```
Error in strata(Guns, (levels(Guns$state)), size = c(40), method = "srswor") : 
  the names of the strata are wrong
```

THANKS!

Comment: Stratified random sampling is sampling within strata/each stratum.  So, for the first step when strata are being sampled, I think you will have to make a random sample only.

Answer (score 1):

For random sample do these simple steps

```
set.seed(2)
x <- sample(unique(Guns$state), 40)

sample <- Guns[Guns$state %in% x,]

> nrow(Guns)
[1] 1173
> nrow(sample)
[1] 920
```

920/1173 rows selected

check number of states in sample

```
> length(unique(sample$state))
[1] 40
```

For stratified sampling within this sample of 40 States say 50% selection per State, follow this code

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(2)
str_sample <- sample %>% group_by(state) %>%
  sample_frac(size = 0.5)
```

If you'll see 480 rows are selected.  Check each stratum size

```
> table(sample$state)

             Alabama               Alaska              Arizona             Arkansas           California             Colorado          Connecticut 
                  23                   23                   23                    0                    0                   23                    0 
            Delaware District of Columbia              Florida              Georgia               Hawaii                Idaho             Illinois 
                  23                   23                    0                   23                   23                   23                   23 
             Indiana                 Iowa               Kansas             Kentucky            Louisiana                Maine             Maryland 
                  23                   23                   23                   23                   23                   23                   23 
       Massachusetts             Michigan            Minnesota          Mississippi             Missouri              Montana             Nebraska 
                  23                   23                   23                   23                    0                   23                    0 
              Nevada        New Hampshire           New Jersey           New Mexico             New York       North Carolina         North Dakota 
                  23                   23                    0                   23                   23                   23                   23 
                Ohio             Oklahoma               Oregon         Pennsylvania         Rhode Island       South Carolina         South Dakota 
                  23                   23                   23                   23                    0                   23                    0 
           Tennessee                Texas                 Utah              Vermont             Virginia           Washington        West Virginia 
                   0                   23                   23                   23                   23                   23                   23 
           Wisconsin              Wyoming 
                   0                   23 

> table(str_sample$state)

             Alabama               Alaska              Arizona             Arkansas           California             Colorado          Connecticut 
                  12                   12                   12                    0                    0                   12                    0 
            Delaware District of Columbia              Florida              Georgia               Hawaii                Idaho             Illinois 
                  12                   12                    0                   12                   12                   12                   12 
             Indiana                 Iowa               Kansas             Kentucky            Louisiana                Maine             Maryland 
                  12                   12                   12                   12                   12                   12                   12 
       Massachusetts             Michigan            Minnesota          Mississippi             Missouri              Montana             Nebraska 
                  12                   12                   12                   12                    0                   12                    0 
              Nevada        New Hampshire           New Jersey           New Mexico             New York       North Carolina         North Dakota 
                  12                   12                    0                   12                   12                   12                   12 
                Ohio             Oklahoma               Oregon         Pennsylvania         Rhode Island       South Carolina         South Dakota 
                  12                   12                   12                   12                    0                   12                    0 
           Tennessee                Texas                 Utah              Vermont             Virginia           Washington        West Virginia 
                   0                   12                   12                   12                   12                   12                   12 
           Wisconsin              Wyoming 
                   0                   12
```